# Makefile error with Objective-C with Cocoa on Linux

Tags: objective-c, linux, ubuntu, cocoa, makefile

I'm trying to write a makefile to compile Objective-C with Cocoa on Linux.

I have installed the following packages:

```
sudo apt-get install gnustep gnustep-devel
```

I started with a minimal makefile, which compiles successfully:

```
FLAGS = $(shell gnustep-config --objc-flags)
LIBS = $(shell gnustep-config --base-libs)

all:
    gcc $(FLAGS) HelloWorld.m $(LIBS) -o a.out
```

Here is the sole source file:

```
#include <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
 NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
 NSLog(@"Hello, World!");

[pool drain];
 return 0;
}
```

Now I'm trying to write a more elaborate makefile but I haven't been able to get it working yet:

```
CC = gcc
SOURCES=HelloWorld.m
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.m=.o)
CFLAGS=-c $(shell gnustep-config --objc-flags)
LIBRARIES = $(shell gnustep-config --base-libs)
FRAMEWORKS:= -framework Foundation -framework Cocoa -framework AppKit
LDFLAGS=$(LIBRARIES) $(FRAMEWORKS)
EXECUTABLE=a.out

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

.m.o: 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LIBRARIES) $< -o $@
```

Output:

```
$ make
gcc -rdynamic -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -shared-libgcc -shared-libgcc -pthread -fexceptions -fgnu-runtime -L/home/brett/GNUstep/Library/Libraries -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -lgnustep-base -lobjc -lm -framework Foundation -framework Cocoa -framework AppKit HelloWorld.o -o a.out
gcc: error: Foundation: No such file or directory
gcc: error: Cocoa: No such file or directory
gcc: error: AppKit: No such file or directory
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-framework’
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-framework’
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-framework’
Makefile:14: recipe for target 'a.out' failed
make: *** [a.out] Error 1
```

Gcc version:

```
gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 7.2.0-8ubuntu3' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-7 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 7.2.0 (Ubuntu 7.2.0-8ubuntu3) gnustep-config --base-libs


$ gnustep-config --objc-flags
-MMD -MP -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -DGNUSTEP -DGNUSTEP_BASE_LIBRARY=1 -DGNU_GUI_LIBRARY=1 -DGNU_RUNTIME=1 -DGNUSTEP_BASE_LIBRARY=1 -fno-strict-aliasing -fexceptions -fobjc-exceptions -D_NATIVE_OBJC_EXCEPTIONS -pthread -fPIC -Wall -DGSWARN -DGSDIAGNOSE -Wno-import -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/gnustep-make-1owDvd/gnustep-make-2.6.8=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/gnustep-make-1owDvd/gnustep-make-2.6.8=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fgnu-runtime -fconstant-string-class=NSConstantString -I. -I/home/brett/GNUstep/Library/Headers -I/usr/local/include/GNUstep -I/usr/include/GNUstep

$ gnustep-config --base-libs
-rdynamic -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -shared-libgcc -shared-libgcc -pthread -fexceptions -fgnu-runtime -L/home/brett/GNUstep/Library/Libraries -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -lgnustep-base -lobjc -lm
brett@brett-desktop:~/Git/Mandelbrot/Mandelbrot2$ gnustep-config --base-libsgnustep-config --base-libs
```

Actually I think I see the problem, my gnustep-config --base-libs outputs -L/home/brett/GNUstep/Library/Libraries which does not exist in my environment. I will update if I figure out how to properly install the libraries.

It appears as if the gnustep-devel package only installed the docs:

```
$ dpkg-query -L gnustep-devel
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/gnustep-devel
/usr/share/doc/gnustep-devel/copyright
/usr/share/doc/gnustep-devel/changelog.gz
```

I found some files under /usr/share/GNUstep but no Foundation.h:

```
$ find . -name *.h
./Makefiles/TestFramework/ObjectTesting.h
./Makefiles/TestFramework/Testing.h
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try this :

```
CC = gcc
SOURCES=HelloWorld.m
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.m=.o)
CCFLAGS=`gnustep-config --objc-flags` -c
OBJCLIBS=`gnustep-config --objc-libs` -lgnustep-base

EXECUTABLE=a.out

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(OBJCLIBS)

%.o     :   %.m
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
```

I did not check in detail but with your makefile all "-I" directives are missing like this :

```
-I/usr/local/include/GNUstep -I/usr/include/GNUstep
```